# GA4 says Not Found under Reports>Pages and Screens

Tags: google-analytics-4

I did a site audit and also added "page and screen titles" as an attribute in the report. There aren't any 404 pages. Even conversion events are coming from this page.

While checking this out, one thing that kept coming in is that GA is failing to attribute pages with its title. Can someone explain what I should do here? How do I resolve this?Adding screenshots for better understanding[image: GA Image]

Comment: You could use the little blue + to add a secondary dimension. I think it's called "page path" or similar. Then you can work out the URL that title relates to.

Comment: Hey @TonyMcCreath, so I added the dimension, and it didn't show up anything, which means it is not 404 error. What else I should be doing?

Comment: There was no path? All pages should have a path that you could use to re-create the URL and test to see if it is a 404.